# Need C# linq query for pivot data

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Order table with some fields. And I need two of them now: `PostalCode` and `TimeSlot`. And the structure is like below:

[image: DB table structure]

And what I need is a structure like below (need Linq query in C#).

[image: Required structure]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: links to external sources is not good, make sure everything you needed is available in SO

Comment: quick, before the downvoters get here :)

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: You should read the [FAQ] and [ask]. Show what you tried and where it fails when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along those lines:

```
//taken from LinqPad. Dump() will not work anywhere else.
void Main()
{
    var source = new List<Order> {
        new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="A" },
        new Order {ZipCode = "02", TimeSlot ="B" },
        new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="B" },
        new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="C" }
    };

    var pivotedOrders = source.GroupBy (s => s.ZipCode)
                              .Select(o => new {
                                ZipCode = o.Key,
                                OrdersCount = o.Count(),
                                A = o.Count(x => x.TimeSlot == "A"),
                                B = o.Count(x => x.TimeSlot == "B"),
                                C = o.Count(x => x.TimeSlot == "C")
                              })
                              .Dump();
}

public class Order
{
    public string ZipCode {get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot {get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. Its working fine. But the only problem here is we are statically finding the timeslots like ="A".. The code can be kept unaltered in future if this can be done dynamically. I mean something like pivot in sql.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ you cannot create dynamic object on the fly. You should try with the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), but honestly I don't have any experience with it.

The solution that I would adopt is this: instead of an object with a property for each time slot, I would build an object like this:

```
class PivotData
{
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int OrdersCount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> TimeSlots {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see it contains a dictionary with a key value pair of string and int: the string is the name of the time slot, the int is the count.

Based on this object, you can write your LINQ code as the following:

```
    var source = new List<Order> {
    new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="A" },        
    new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="A" },
    new Order {ZipCode = "02", TimeSlot ="B" },
        new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="B" },
        new Order {ZipCode = "01", TimeSlot ="C" }
    };

    var result = source
        .GroupBy(s => s.ZipCode)
        .Select(g => new PivotData
                {
                    ZipCode = g.Key,
                    OrdersCount = g.Count(),
                    TimeSlots = g.GroupBy(x => x.TimeSlot).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
                }).ToList();

    foreach(var item in result) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ZipCode: " + item.ZipCode + " - " + "Orders count: " + item.OrdersCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Time slots:");
        foreach(var timeSlot in item.TimeSlots) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(timeSlot.Key + " - " + timeSlot.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---");
    }
```